# How can I get Jmeter info Logs while running distributed testing?

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

I want to run Jmeter distributed testing, I want Jmeter to write info logs on log file but in distributed mode it only provides us logs which is related to connection, it doesnot really gives the log of execution.
How can I get the actual logs?? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The execution log is being written on **slave** side, if you run slave via `jmeter-server.bat` or `jmeter-server` you should see **jmeter-server.log** file in the folder where you launched slave instance from.

If you don't see the log file you can specify its name and location via [-j command line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -s -j jmeter-server.log ......
```

More information:

- [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: In my case the Worker Remote Nodes are all Docker instances, is there a way we can have a consolidated jmeter.log as i am also measuring the Start and End times of the Thread Group